# Does the Master at Arms feat work for Shields?

Tags: dnd-4e, feats, shield

Does the `Master at Arms` [[ddi](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/display.aspx?page=feat&id=3145)] feat work for Shields?

> **Benefit:** You gain a +1 feat bonus to the attack rolls of weapon attacks. The bonus increases to +2 at 11th level and +3 at 21st level.
>       Also, you can use a minor action to sheathe a weapon and then draw a weapon.

I tend to think **No**, as the Compendium entry about `Weapons` says ...

> **Weapon**
>   Many martial powers, as well as several divine powers, can be used only if you’re wielding a weapon. (You can use an unarmed attack as your weapon.) A weapon’s reach or range determines the reach or range of a power it’s used with.

and `Shields` don't have a `Reach`, and it takes a `Standard Action` to stow or equip, rather than the `Minor Action` for a *Weapon*

Comment: Hey steve, if you're going to `backquote` game-specific nouns, the DDI compendium is *not* a game specific noun in context of the other nouns so indicated. Backquoting it just makes things confusing.

Comment: Actually, looking on meta, @SteveC, could you hold to the community standard [here](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/a/1504/760)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No, with one exception.**

In general, shields are *not* weapons. Note that in PHB1, shields are listed with armor on page 214, rather than with weapons on pages 218 to 219. The `Master at Arms` feat only allows you to quick draw weapons, and shields are not weapons...

...Unless it's a `spiked shield`, which counts as both a light shield *and* a weapon. Sure it doesn't make much sense to strap a shield to your arm that fast, or unstrap it, but I have trouble believing someone could realistically stow a greatbow and draw a mordenkrad in a single minor action either. `Master at Arms` says you can do both, though.

Comment: I guess welding spikes to your shield is equivalent to painting your vehicle red?

Comment: @Tacroy that whole superior-weapon thing has it's benefits

Answer (score 2):

The attack bonus applies (as it refers to the keyword of the attack, not the weapon that is being used) to `weapon` attacks made with shields. But the minor action sheathe + draw cannot be used with a shield.

Like you said the standard action cost for stowing/equipping a shield means it's quite different from a weapon in this matter.

A better question is whether this drawing/stowing economy is present with a `spiked shield` item. I still don't think it would be (it's still strapped to your arm), but it's usable as a weapon so technically this feat would apply to it.

Comment: Yeah, the Spike Shield is still a shield, but it's very confusing as it can be enchanted as either a weapon or a shield item